# How Four Natures created which are described in Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita, brahma, caste-system

Lord Shri Krishna said regarding four Natures to Arjuna in Bhagavad Gita.

In this Sloka of Bhagavad Gita:

> ब्राह्मणक्षत्रियविशां शूद्राणां च परंतप।
>
> कर्माणि प्रविभक्तानि स्वभावप्रभवैर्गुणैः।।18.41।।

"The nature of Brahmanas, Ksatriyas, Vaisyas, and Sudras are due to their respective inherent dispositions. The meaning is that their past Karma has been the cause of determining births as Brahmanas etc. The Sattva and other Gunas are the result of such Karma.... The duties and works assigned to them according to the Gunas constituting their inherent nature, are expounded and allotted by the Sastras in the order described."

Here I m only talking about the four Natures
**Brahmanas, Ksatriyas, Vaisyas, and Sudras**.
So, How four Natures came into existence according to Scripture?

Comment: That's not a very good translation; the verse is not saying that Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, etc. are distinguished by qualities of work, it says the duties of Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, etc. are based on the gunas inherent in those castes.

Comment: Here's what Ramanujacharya says in his Bhagavad Gita Bhashya: "The nature of Brahmanas, Ksatriyas, Vaisyas, and Sudras are due to their respective inherent dispositions. The meaning is that their past Karma has been the cause of determining births as Brahmanas etc. The Sattva and other Gunas are the result of such Karma.... The duties and works assigned to them according to the Gunas constituting their inherent nature, are expounded and allotted by the Sastras in the order described."

Comment: I m just took the sloka where lord Krishna mentioned this four Caste , and I m not talking about their gunas,

Comment: I'm just saying the verse hasn't been translated properly.  The verse does not say qualities of work.

Comment: Ok got it I take your translation , thanks ! I will edit in my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, In the Bhagavad Gita, Lord Krishna told in Moksha-Sanyasyog about the Natures and their respective modes.

These all four Natures created by lord Brahma himself.

I found the source of it.
Creation of Four Natures is described in the **Padma Puran of Shristhi Khand**

> On being asked by Bhishma about the origin of the four prominent
>   castes, Sage Pulastya said--- Lord Brahma created the Brahmins and
>   the Kshatriyas from his mouth and chest respectively. Similarly,
>   Vaishyas and Shudras manifested from Lord Brahma's thigh and feet
>   respectively.

**Note**: If anyone can find Sanskrit verse of above explanation feel free to add it in.

Comment: लोकांनां तु विवृद्धी-अर्थ मुख -बाहू-उरु-पादतः l 
 ब्राम्हणं क्षत्रियं वैश्यम शूद्रमं निरवर्तयत ll
Here is similar shlokas i have found in manusmriti  1-31.                     Meaning - for the sake of prosperity of the world he caused the Brahmana,Kshatriya,vaisya and sudra to proceed from his mouth ,his arms, his thighs and his feet.

Comment: Great keep edit it in answer , I already said,..

Comment: ,Namaste , but I have given answer to your previous statment of similar verses.    its ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

Purush Sukta, hymn 10.90 of Rigveda describes creation of four varnas as such. http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/vedas-purusha_suktam.php

> ब्राह्मणोऽस्य मुखमासीद् बाहू राजन्यः कृतः ।
>   ऊरू तदस्य यद्वैश्यः पद्भ्यां शूद्रो अजायत ॥१२॥
>   Braahmanno-Asya Mukham-Aasiid Baahuu Raajanyah Krtah |
>   Uuruu Tad-Asya Yad-Vaishyah Padbhyaam Shuudro Ajaayata ||12||
>
> Meaning:
>   12.1: The Brahmanas were His Mouth, the Kshatriyas became His Arms,
>   12.2: The Vaishyas were His Thighs, and from His pair of Feet were born the Shudras.

Btw translation of Bhagwad Gita verse you have posted is more commentary from particular sampradaya than word to word translation. Here is word to word translation from http://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/41

> brāhmaṇa—of the priestly class; kṣhatriya—the warrior and administrative class; viśhām—the mercantile and farming class; śhūdrāṇām—of the worker class; cha—and; parantapa—Arjun, subduer of the enemies; karmāṇi—duties; pravibhaktāni—distributed; svabhāva-prabhavaiḥ-guṇaiḥ—work based on one’s nature and guṇas